# How can I prevent my eye-glasses from becoming blurred when riding a motorcycle when raining?

Tags: vehicle

I have a motorcycle and I am always wearing a glasses, whenever it is raining I always wear a raincoat and a helmet. This prevents my head and body from becoming wet, please note that my helmet doesn't cover my whole head, it only covers about the half of my face and it doesn't have some transparent plastic that covers my eyesight.

**My question:** Although I am wearing a helmet oftentimes my eye-glasses becomes wet, and I think that even if I wear a helmet that a transparent plastic it will still make my vision blurred. How do I prevent this?

I am planning to do the following, but still hesitating.

1. Buy a full head covered helmet that has a transparent plastic
2. Maybe put a hat and removed my helmet? (To avoid my eye-glasses from being wet from the rain)

Comment: Replacing a helmet with a hat (whether it is raining or not) when driving a motorcycle is really dangerous! Please do try a full helmet.

Answer (score 3):

Apply an automobile hard paste wax to the front of your glasses (or your helmet visor) per the usage instructions. This will keep the rain from sticking to the surface which is obscuring your vision. The "non-stick surface" you create will cause the rain to sheet off very *very* quickly keeping your vision essentially clear.

Try it. It works.

I suggest testing this out on your *car* windshield first. For safety reasons, this will allow you to see if the level of clarity is improved with the type/brand of wax you are using, and still have your wipers available if it doesn't. But I'll bet you see that *vast* improvement, even in your automobile.

Comment: And if you get a helmet with a plastic face cover, you could still use this hard paste wax on the plastic face cover to make sure rain slides off of that.

Comment: A slight twist on this: Rain-X.  You could even cheat and get the windshield wiper fluid with Rain-X in it (where I live it's like $2.50 at Wal-mart), use a bit on your glasses/helmet visor, and put the rest of the gallon in you car.

Comment: Wow, this seems to be great! I'll check it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Cat crap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002ZNA488). It's a lens cleaner and anti-fog treatment and it is safe on all lenses and great for eyewear, goggles, binoculars and helmet visors.

You rub it on. And you can run it off.

It sheds water and keeps your glasses from fogging.